# Nitro Brews and Sodas

Tags: classical-mechanics, surface-tension

I feel pretty sure this is a mechanics question, so here goes.  I just finished a Nitro Pepsi - Yum!  (I know, 63 grams of sugar.  I had to brush my teeth twice after drinking it!)

It is well known that "nitro" drinks, (Guinness beer is another example), which have nitrogen gas, rather than carbon dioxide, in solution, have smaller bubbles and thus creamier heads.

A bubble, of course, is a gas contained within a liquid film.  If nitrogen containing liquids produce smaller bubbles, it would seem that would be because the pressure of the gas has exceeded the liquid surface tension.  My reasoning here is that the liquid has been cold.  When pouring into the glass, the gas comes out of solution and begins to expand as it warms.  At some bubble diameter, the bubble pops, which should be when the internal pressure exceeds the surface tension.

Bubble Popping means Internal Pressure > Surface Tension

Bubble not Popping means Internal Pressure < Surface Tension

Smaller bubbles mean the internal pressure exceeds the surface tension faster when compared to larger bubbles.  This means that, for some reason, nitrogen containing bubbles reach this point earlier than carbon dioxide containing bubbles.

Is this anywhere close to correct?

Comment: The solubility of nitrogen in water at 1 atm is very low: about 20 mg/L.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider that a nitrogen gas molecule is both lighter and smaller than a carbon dioxide molecule and this plays a part in the size difference between the two bubbles under the same conditions. The different solubilities of the two gases in solution may also play a role. I don't believe either gas is altering the surface tension significantly.